# Communicate beetween two virtual machines through another virtual machine

Tags: python, virtual-machine, iptables, kvm, bridge

Here is my problem. I have 3 virtual machines running on linux and three bridges
Each of them have two interface (one for each bridge)
For example:

- VM1 : i0 for br0 and i2 for br2
- VM2 : i1 for br1 and i0 for br0
- VM3 : i1 for br1 and i2 for br2

Here are the conditions:
 - VM1 and VM3 have to communicate between them through VM2
 - packets going from VM1 to VM3 go through br0 and br1
 - but packets from VM3 to VM1 go only through br2

```
                      <-------
   ---------------------br2-------------------
   |                                         |
**VM1**----br0-----**VM2**-----br1--------**VM3**
         ------>              -------->
```

My first idea was to use the NAT thanks to iptables rules but I am not sure it's gonna work because packets have to take two differents ways ( br0-br1 and br2)

My second one was to use python script with scappy

Do you have any idea ?

Sorry for my poor english. As you can see, I'm not proficient in english at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the VMs are in the same IP subnet, they will try to reach directly one another.

Now, for example, you want to force VM1 to talk to VM3 trough VM2. If you let VM1 figure out how to reach VM3, it will broadcast an arp request and VM3 will respond *"hey, that's me! Here is my mac address"*. So VM1 will then send IP packets directly to VM3.

But... you can *fool* VM1 by adding to it's arp cache an entry with VM3 IP address associated to VM2 mac address. In linux you do that with:

```
arp -s <IP address> <mac address>
```

So, now when VM1 has to talk to VM3, it will **not** do an arp request, because it already *knows* the destination's mac address. It will happily send IP packets for VM3 to VM2's NIC. At this point, assuming VM2 accepts doing some packet forwarding and it doesn't have iptables rules inhibiting such thing, it will then resend the packets to the *real* VM3.

Maybe you don't even need all those bridges too, unless you need them for other reasons.

If this solution works for you, the arp cache entry can be made *permanent* by adding a line in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
up arp -s <IP address> <mac address>
```

This way, the arp cache entry is set every time the NIC is brought up (i.e. when the machine boots).